# How to push new geofencing locations with appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, geofencing, appcelerator-arrow

I have an app built in appcelerator, and I have upgraded to use the geofencing module. I want to be able to set new locations and push those to the app, which I thought could be done with push notifications.

In the appcelerator dashboard, there is a place to create "places" and "geofencing" entries. I have done this. But I'm not sure how to get that into the app. Since it looks like they have to be registered within the app:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Geofence

Am I supposed to write code that downloads these and registers them? Is it possible to do this within a push notification somehow?

Can i trigger a process with a push notification that will be able to register the new locations without having to open the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create geofences server-side using the API:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/GeoFences-method-create

The module has an example on how to fetch these from the server and then set them on the device.

Comment: It's my understanding that this just creates is in appcelerators cloud database under geofences - but that it doesn't affect the app at all - the app still has to download from this database to update it's registered watch locations

Comment: You are correct. I updated my answer. Since the geofences are a device feature I guess there's no way around that. The only other way would be to constantly monitor location and send it to server (which is more intensive) and then send (silent) push notifications when in a certain area.